# missing FROM-clause entry for table in psql update query

Tags: sql, postgresql

For this query, I'm getting the error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "public"`. Why?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE public."Devices"

SET DeviceType = 2
WHERE public."Devices.LocationId" = 5; -- error here
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the double quotes in the wrong place:

```
UPDATE public."Devices"
    SET DeviceType = 2
    WHERE public."Devices"."LocationId" = 5;
```

Or, use an alias:

```
UPDATE public."Devices" d
    SET DeviceType = 2
    WHERE d."LocationId" = 5;
```

And, don't use quoted identifiers!  They are such a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is the simplest syntax I could use:

```
UPDATE public."Devices"
    SET "DeviceType" = 2
    WHERE "LocationId" = 5;
```